# Not able to Access the JSON getting error

Tags: json, angular

I am not able to access json. PFB json

I am trying to access:-

`this.businessSwitchName = d.businessSwitchDetails.nodeName;`

and trying to bind to html via interpolation

```
var d:any = {
    "service": "091PUNE623017759708",
    "routerDetails": {
        "nodeName": null,
        "portName": null,
        "nodeIP": null,
        "nodeID": null
    },
    "agsDetails": {
        "nodeName": null,
        "portName": null,
        "nodeIP": null,
        "nodeID": null
    },
    "businessSwitchDetails": {
        "nodeName": "Dyaneshwar Park",
        "portName": null,
        "nodeIP": "10.171.4.3",
        "nodeID": "365429"
    },
    "handoffPort": null,
    "qosLoopingPort": null
}
```

But getting this error:

[image: this error]

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'businessSwitchDetails' of undefined
    at ContactFormComponent.push../src/app/contact-form/contact-form.component.ts.ContactFormComponent.onChange (contact-form.component.ts:16)
    at Object.eval (ContactFormComponent.html:48)
    at handleEvent (core.js:9953)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11046)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:10749)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7415)
    at core.js:7859
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:1140)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3662)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment so need to do this in a answer, but you need to show some more information.

Where do you initialize the variable d, because it seems like d is not in the same scope as businessSwitchName

---

You initialize the variable d after trying to use it. 
Which means while you try to do:

```
this.businessSwitchName = d.businessSwitchDetails.nodeName;
```

Variable d is still undefined, so you should first define d and than do something with it.

So make your onChange() method something like this:

```
onChange(){
var d = {"service": "091PUNE623017759708",
"routerDetails": {
    "nodeName": null,
    "portName": null,
    "nodeIP": null,
    "nodeID": null
},
"agsDetails": {
    "nodeName": null,
    "portName": null,
    "nodeIP": null,
    "nodeID": null
},
"businessSwitchDetails": {
    "nodeName": "Dyaneshwar Park",
    "portName": null,
    "nodeIP": "10.171.4.3",
    "nodeID": "365429"
},
"handoffPort": null,
"qosLoopingPort": null};


  this.businessSwitchName = d.businessSwitchDetails.nodeName;
  this.businessSwitchIp = d.businessSwitchDetails.nodeIP;
  this.portName = d.businessSwitchDetails.portName;

  let da = {
  "serviceAttribute": {
    "serviceType": "GVPN",
    "category": "category",
    "name": "091PUNE623017759708"
  },
  "btsIp": "10.171.4.3"
};

  console.log(da);

  this.service.portService(da).
    subscribe (response => {
        console.log(response);

    });  
}

}
```

Comment: there's a reason why you can comment. please don't use answers

Comment: @R4LPH Still getting the same error!!
I have moved all this. statements after defining var d

Comment: Oh I see, you should also initialize businessSwitchName with a default string in line 2.

Comment: businessSwitchName: string = "";

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'businessSwitchDetails' of undefined

As above statement says itself that we are tyring to access `businessSwitchDetails` property of `undefined`, states that object `d` is not defined.

**Ways to debug :**

- Do `console.log(d);` before this line of code `this.businessSwitchName = d.businessSwitchDetails.nodeName;` to check whether you are getting proper response or not.
- Check the value of `d`. It should be `JSON object` instead of `JSON string`.
- Check the sequence of the execution of the statements. It should be object `d` initialization first then statement to access the property `businessSwitchDetails`.